# JavaFX Image in other package

Tags: java, css

I have a number of different packages in my project, to keep all files separated and organised. It's all working great, apart from one thing: I can't get a proper link to images.. I use a css file to style my JavaFX application, and am trying to implement a background image.

```
.root{
     -fx-background-image: url("background.jpg");
}
```

The problem I've run into is as follows:

My css file is in the package *eu.name.projectname.style* while the image file is in the folder *eu.name.projectname.images*. Since it's not a subdirectory of the style directory, I can't simply add /images/ to the code.. How would I change it so I can specify the entire path? E.g.

```
.root{
    -fx-background-image: url("eu/name/projectname/images/background.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Anyone? I could really use some help..

Comment: I'd really appreciate an answer..

Comment: Anybody?... Desperate here.